# Alfresco Ldap create a group folder as home folder for users

Tags: alfresco, openldap, alfresco-share, alfresco-ldap

I´m using Alfresco-LDAP to migrate all my ldap users to Alfresco service.

So far I achieve transfer all users but for every user the home folder created in Alfresco for them is his name, and what I would like, is to share a folder for all members of the ldap group, since I have multiple groups and every user of that group only can get files from that group.

This is the property

```
       ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider
```

I read in the Alfresco documentation http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Security_and_Authentication#Creating_home_spaces_-_from_1.4_onwards 
But seems like what I´m trying to do is not contemplated.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there is no configurable HomeFolderProvider for groups supporting specific spaces. You need to crate your own HomeFolderProvider in Java for that. Out of the box you could use the companyHomeFolderProvider which is normally used if you want to disable the homefolder feature. The user object requires a userhome to be able to log in and the work around is to set the root (company_home) for that.

s.

[1] https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Security_and_Authentication#Creating_home_spaces_-_from_1.4_onwards

[2] [Disable the user home folder creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479232/disable-the-user-home-folder-creation)